# How can I make cowboy recompile all files in ./src when I use gmake run?

Tags: erlang, cowboy

I use gmake run to launch my cowboy server.

If I don't have the `beam` files in /src, I'll run into errors.

How can I make `gmake run` compile these?

Comment: Can you add more info? I can run an cowboy example without problems using `gmake run` are you using  `erlang.mk` ?

Comment: Hm, so things are working for me now. Seems to be compiling. I'm confused as to what happened though here -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41926793/erlang-shell-stopped-loading-my-modules/41927017#41927017